# Is there a way I can connect to a MERN app from a different network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, mern

My question is pretty straight forward. I am able to connect to my MERN app inside my local network by adding rules to allow incoming connections to the necesary ports (9901 for my server, 3000 for my client, and 27017 for my database), then deactivating the Firewall on my active internet connection on my computer.
Can I do something similar but that allows connections coming from outside of my local network? Let's say, through a use of a VPN for example.